# What are the changes needed in my existing Excel VBA code to meet this specific task?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2016. I need to transpose data from several workbooks (each containing different amount of worksheets). All the worksheets are in the same format and all the columns that need to be transposed for each worksheet begin at the same place (say, column D). However, each worksheet can contain a different number of columns to be transposed (that is, Worksheet 1 may have columns D to E, Worksheet 2 may have Cols D to G, and so on...).

I already have a VBA code that I can run to do the job (more on this below) but my main problem is that I need to manually change the code each time I need to run it on a Worksheet because the range of data that I need to transpose differ from worksheet to worksheet.

Here is my existing VBA Code:

```
Sub TransposeColumns()
Dim i As Long
Dim RW As Long

With Sheets("ORIGINAL")
For i = 4 To 10 'CHANGE VALUE HERE; MAX NUMBER SHOULD BE NUMBER OF  COLUMNS IN ORIGINAL WORKSHEET
     RW = 1 + Sheets("output").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
     .Range("A2:C74").Copy Sheets("output").Range("A" & RW) 'CHANGE RANGE VALUES
     .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(74, i)).Copy Sheets("output").Range("D" & RW) 'CHANGE RANGE VALUES
     Sheets("output").Range("E" & RW).Resize(73) = .Cells(1, i).Value
     'CHANGE RESIZE VALUE;RESIZE VALUE SHOULD BE MAX RANGE VALUE - 1
 Next i
 End With
 End Sub
```

Here is Original data from Workbook 1 - Worksheet named "Feb 2015":

```
 col A    col B     col C   col D
 HOTEL    RATING    PLAN    22/08/2014
  EBA       3        AI        88 
  VER       3        AI        85 
  TRO       3        AI        91
```

And this is what I get when running my existing VBA code on that Worksheet:

```
EBA    3    AI   88   22/08/2014
VER    3    AI   85   22/08/2014
TRO    3    AI   91   22/08/2014
```

Now, in that same Workbook, I may have another Worksheet named, say, "Jun 2015" and it might look like this:

```
col A    col B     col C   col D          col E
 HOTEL    RATING    PLAN    22/04/2014   25/05/2014
  EBA       3        AI        69          58
  VER       3        AI        80          60
  TRO       3        AI        90          98
```

Right now, I need to run my vba code 2 times, once for each worksheet. Also I need to rename the worksheet as "ORIGINAL" as per my vba code.

I need to change the vba code so that it does the following:

(1) automatically determine the range needed to transpose the required columns (based on the fact that the columns needed to be transposed will always start from Column D)
(2) automatically add a new column to the transposed data and fill that column with the name of the worksheet
(3) the vba code should run across all worksheets in the Workbook and output all the results in one single new worksheet

So, basically here's the output I am looking for based on the examples above with a Workbook having only 2 worksheets named "Feb 2015" and "Jun 2015" respectively:

```
EBA    3    AI   88   22/08/2014   Feb 2015
VER    3    AI   85   22/08/2014   Feb 2015
TRO    3    AI   91   22/08/2014   Feb 2015
EBA    3    AI   69   22/04/2014   Jun 2015
VER    3    AI   80   22/04/2014   Jun 2015
TRO    3    AI   90   22/04/2014   Jun 2015
EBA    3    AI   58   25/05/2014   Jun 2015
VER    3    AI   60   25/05/2014   Jun 2015
TRO    3    AI   98   25/05/2014   Jun 2015
```

Note: I must also add that the number of Rows differ from worksheet to worksheet and I need the vba code to automatically take that into account too.

Comment: Power Query makes it easier to Unpivot data https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: I've had a look at Power Query but I guess I still need to run it manually through each worksheet in my workbook. Or does Power Query have a feature that allows it to run through the whole workbook at a go?

Comment: you can select multiple workbooks and sheets with `From File` > `From Folder` and remove or filter the sheets and columns that you don't need. After done, the steps can be stored like a macro and re-run at later time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try but if it cannot perform number (2) above, ie: automatically add a new column to the transposed data and fill that column with the name of the worksheet, it would get complicated to so AFTER it has merged all the transposed data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write your program for you, I think you should have focussed on those parts of VBA you have yet to learn and asked them, (actually google them).

Anyway, some tips with which you can complete your task

To find out the number of rows one get a range variable, say `rng` one has

```
Debug.Print "rowcount=" & rng.Rows.Count
```

for column count

```
Debug.Print "columncount=" & rng.Columns.Count
```

to find an edge of a block of cells you already have an example, you start in a blank cell and head towards the block so in your code you have

```
Sheets("output").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

which will find the lowest row of a block of cells in A column.

You can even use UsedRange which given a cell will find all the range enveloping the surrounding block.

```
Sheets("output").Cells(1,1).UsedRange
```

You are now equipped to complete your task. :)